# RT3290 Ralink driver in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, ralink

I have found that there is a large community suffering from the problems with the WiFi-Bluetooth card Ralink RT-3290. It has been a problem since 2012-2013.

None of the solutions I've found is simple, effective and durable.

I managed, with great effort, some results. But when there is a kernel update, the problems return.

Can anyone provide a simple , effective and lasting solution?
Is there a project from Ubuntu's developers to attack the problem?

Comment: The kernel developers weren't getting any help from the manufacturer in this case and there is a special interface involved if I remember correctly

Comment: Thank you. I know that there is no help from the manufacturer. And the bugs are reported for a long time. Internet is full of refrencias and PPA to this particular problem with Ralink RT3290. I've tried everything. The rbth-dkms driver (with modifications and after hard work) does work (not perfectly) at least in kernel versions lower than 3.15. In that case, one skilled enough to adapt it to make it work adjusting to the new BT kernel API. My knowledge is not enough.
So I am surprised that some expert community has not found an effective packaged solution. Because it is a widespread problem.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the answer above is a steps in a correct direction. There are only two steps missing.

Step-by-step solution
Open new terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type as follows:

```
 sudo apt install git
 mkdir ~/tmp
 cd ~/tmp
 git clone https://github.com/alinefr/rtbth.git
 cd rtbth
 make
 sudo make install
 sudo cp -r ~/rtbth /usr/src/rtbth-3.9.3
 sudo dkms install rtbth/3.9.3
 sudo nano /etc/modules
```

Add `rtbth` to the end of the file, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (to save the file) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to close the editor

Then reboot and the new driver will be loaded.

This one worked for me to get the Bluetooth to be active and find devices, however, I didn't succeeded to pair my Jabra play clipper with it, but that might be due to the Jabra device problems.

Anyway, you can try it out and share your progress with us

Answer (score 2):

I also was facing the same problem and I tried all the solution I could find and still could not solve it, most I was able to reach was that all the Bluetooth devices were showing but I was not able to connect to any of them.

But I just today finally found something that works and is very easy to install, it is located on github [rtbth-dkms](https://github.com/loimu/rtbth-dkms).

To Install,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blaze/rtbth-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtbth-dkms
```

and then follow the `Init` commands below, your BlueTooth will work now, in case of any problem leave a comment,  I will be happy to help you.

**Usage**

```
# Init
sudo modprobe rtbth
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
hcitool dev # check

# Switch off
sudo rfkill block bluetooth

# Switch on
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth

# Shutdown
sudo pkill -2 rtbt
sudo rmmod rtbth
```

Answer (score 1):

For bluetooth support there is an updated rtbth version for latest kernel versions (it works in my 4.4.6)

Here is the URL: https://github.com/alinefr/rtbth

From Ubuntu you need to

```
make
sudo make install
sudo dkms install rtbth/3.9.3
```

The kernel module is called `rtbth`

For Wireless support, latest kernel from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus), at the moment, 4.4.0 should work out of the box with `rt2800pci` module.

Comment: It is not working. I have HP 250 G3 with Ralink RT3290. I am trying to get my wireless working for 2 hours and no success.
Is it so complicate to fix a problem that is know from 3 years???
I am new Ubuntu user wanted to try Windows alternative. Guess what will not use it anymore.

Comment: I also have HP 250 G3, and the solution I posted below worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using 16.10.

You should replace

```
HCI_BREDR
```

with

```
HCI_PRIMARY
```

in `rtbth_core_bluez.c`.

Comment: For this answer to be really useful, you should include sterps as tp how that can be achieved

Comment: can't find the file!

Comment: The file in question is in the downloaded source directory itself, this solves the error during `make`

Comment: I read related sourcefiles and found the solution.