# RT3290 Ralink driver in Ubuntu 20.04 not working

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, 20.04, ralink

I have recently upgraded my system from Ubuntu 18.04 to **20.04**. After the upgrade my Bluetooth driver stopped working.
Earlier I had made it working in 18.04 following the post [RT3290 Ralink driver in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756166/rt3290-ralink-driver-in-ubuntu#82892). But the same solution is not helping me with 20.04.

I executed the suggested commands and initially it appeared helping by providing a value for hci0

```
$ sudo modprobe rtbth
$ sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
$ hcitool dev # check
Devices:
    hci0    9C:D2:1E:2A:56:04
```

But It is not able to find any Bluetooth device from GUI. So I tried the commands from terminal.

```
$ hcitool scan
Scanning ...
```

This scanning never ends and does not even find any device while I had enabled my Bluetooth speakers waiting for connection. The same happens for my other Bluetooth devices also.

When I tried the `bluetoothctl` tool:

```
$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent is already registered
[bluetooth]# scan on
[bluetooth]#
```

Scan on command does not do any thing and returns control to the `[bluetooth]#` prompt.

Comment: Any progress on that matter?