# RT3920 Bluetooth driver(Module) not autoloading on Startup

Tags: drivers, wireless, bluetooth, ralink

First of all I am new to linux and also new on this community. So I had to create this new thread because I was not able comment on the thread where I found a six for my Bluetooth driver.

I have a Ralink RT3920 Wifi+bluetooth pci card, which has a very poor support form Linux as it is pretty outdated.

My Bluetooth was not working, so I followed the following fix

[RT3920 Driver for linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756166/rt3290-ralink-driver-in-ubuntu)

It worked as a charm. My Bluetooth started working.
only the problem is that the module isn't automatically loading on startup
I have added `rtbth` to `\etc\modules\`  but still it isn't loading on startup
Whenever I need to use Bluetooth I have to manually type in the command `sudo modprobe rtbth`

Is there any way to fix this?
How can I automatically run `sudo modprobe rtbth` on startup?
please help

And forgive me for creating a new thread about this. I was not able to comment, as commenting requires 50 reputation points

Comment: Please provide OS/release details.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 (Gnome, Kubuntu, Mate) and other 20.04 based distros like Pop!_OS basically linux kernel 5.4

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it is not in any blacklist inside the files in /etc/modprobe.d (in my case was in rtbth-dkms.conf)

Just apply the path:

```
-backlist rtbth
+#backlist rtbth
```

and it will charge propertly.