# Ralink RT3290 (Wi-Fi, Bluetooth) adapter not found in Kubuntu 21.04

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, 21.04

I have an HP laptop with a 4th gen i3, an NVIDIA 820M GPU and a Ralink RT3290 adapter for Wi-Fi and Bluetooth.
The problem is that my Ralink RT3290 (WiFi, Bluetooth) adapter is not found in Kubuntu 21.04.

I tried many solutions, but none of them solved the problem.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Hey ajay! This might be helpful: https://askubuntu.com/q/756166. BTW, what are the many solutions you have tried? Can you please let us know?

Comment: hi i already use this https://askubuntu.com/q/756166 , but not solved, i think for Linux kernel 5.11 needed  different or update solution

Comment: @Random Person i did everything that this link say but i think solution need upgrade for kubuntu 21.04 kernel 5.11 . still not solve

Comment: ajay, I understand that you have tried everything in the link. But can you provide us more details please? For example: In [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1010999), there are commands mentioned. We would like to know the outputs of the commands in your case. You can edit your question by clicking this link: [edit]. Go through this to understand how to format code: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code